# Windows 10 non-persistent installation (live ISO)

Tags: windows, windows-10, livecd, liveusb

We've got a Windows 10 installation running in an environment where it can occasionally lose power and restart.
However, this sometimes leads to corruption of files.

I've had a look at Windows "To-Go" but this seems to be persistent.
And I've also checked out virtualisation, but that would require us to run a non-persistent Windows 10, in another Windows 10 environment.

Is it possible to install Windows 10 as a "non-persistent live CD"?
So that a user will have a seemingly fresh Windows 10, but doesn't require to re-install it at each startup?

Comment: Check this http://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I believe that is for a persistent installation. Can I make it so that changes will be reverted on reboot?

Comment: It will track user profile changes, new drivers, etc., I do not think that any fully read-only To-go installation is possible now, but do not know. Hirens boot CD has mini Windows XP that work like that.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal indeed, also a lot of Linux installer USB's are non-persistent, I've checked how they do it: "Another option is to create an iso of the system in the state you want it to be. Afterwards use a GRUB2 entry to boot directly from the iso." This may just work for windows To Go as well, but will have to try it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a project called [Win10PE SE](http://theoven.org/index.php?topic=1336.0) which allows you to create a Live Windows 10:

[image]

The project uses WinPE but adds desktop/taskbar and allows you to configure which features you want to add or not during building the ISO.

Comment: Good one, I'll check that out, looks promising. Apart from that, the answer can also be that it's not directly supported by windows?

Comment: this is not supported in Windows and you need those WinPE projects