# How to create Live Windows PE on USB from Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I want to create bootable live Windows PE on USB stick. 
I want to create it from Windows 10 installation i have.

I wonder, how can i achive that? Any instructions?
Is there any special software for this?

Comment: What? You will be unable to make a WinPE image based on your current installation of Windows.  How you add applications to a WinPE image is well documented.  What steps specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: I have other installation. Can you novigate me to One place where can i add apllication to WinPE?

Comment: As I indicated.  The process to add an application to a WinPE image is well documented.  The process of creating and deploying a WinPE image is well documented.  This isn't something you don't do without a basic amount of research.  The purpose of my comment was to tell you, you will be unable to convert your current installlation, into a WinPE image.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1178358/174557

Comment: Great tool @magicandre1981! Please consider write this as an answer so i can vote.

Comment: no, I closed it as duplicate. upvote the [original answer instead](https://superuser.com/a/1178358/174557)